# Django - how to save form with multiple objects?

Tags: python, django, object, django-forms, save

I am using Python3.7, Django 2.2.

Below you can find my code, to better understand my problem.

As you can see my code below, I have created table with some records. Skip polish name of the values in models.py. We have to focus only for manager_accpt. This value has 2 arguments (check file choices.py).

When I create view with def manager_day_free_accpt I get multiple objects. The last column contains choice, which my user have to choose and save. Example I have put in screen below.
What is my problem.
I have to do it in 2 ways, beacause user will choose, which solution is more user friendly for them :)
I have problem with buttons, where should i put them? Because right now, submition change whole objects, but with wrong values.

When I put Buttons outside "for loop", nothing happend with objects. Can you help me, I have to find two solutions for it:

1st:
Every row should contain green button with submit and reject (white button). And when user click on green button, the value only in this raw should update objects in db..

2nd sol:
User choose accept and reject in every row. After that user should push submit button, and all change should update the objects in db.

models.py

```
class Wniosek_urlop(models.Model):
    data_zloz_wniosku = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    data_start_urlop = models.DateField('Urlop od', blank=False, null=True)
    data_end_urlop = models.DateField('Urlop do', blank=False,null=True)
    #Representant - osoba zastepująca w tym czasie nieobecnego pracownika.
    representant = models.CharField('Zastępca', max_length=50, null=False,blank=False,
                                    help_text="Podaj imie i nazwisko osoby zastępującej Cię w czasie nieobecności. To pole będzie widoczne przez kierownika")
    reason = models.TextField('Uzasadnienie', max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Powód złożenia wniosku", error_messages={'blank': "Wpisz tutaj coś"})
    note_optional = models.TextField('Uwagi', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    urlop = models.CharField('Urlop', choices=urlop_ch, default=1, max_length=50)
    manager = models.CharField('Przełożony', choices=manager_ch, default=0, max_length=50)
    manager_accpt = models.CharField('Akceptacja', choices=accpt_ch, null=True, blank=True, max_length=25)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Lista, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def manager_day_free_accpt(request):
    db_all_free_days = Wniosek_urlop.objects.all().order_by('id')

    #Pole wyboru y_n
    form_accpt = Manager_accpt_y_n(request.POST or None)
    if form_accpt.is_valid():
        form_accpt.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Zapisano zmiany.')
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'Ups. Cos poszło nie tak.')

    return render(request, "manager_accpt.html", {'db_all_free_days': db_all_free_days, 'form_accpt': form_accpt})
```

choices.py

```
manager_ch = [("1", "manager 1"),
              ("2", "manager 2")
               ]

accpt_ch = [
    ("1", "accept"),
    ("2", "reject")
]
```

manager_accpt.html

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Pracownik</th>
      <!--Skip some col-->
      <th scope="col">Przełożony</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


  {% for tmp in db_all_free_days %}
    {%if tmp.manager_accpt == null %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{tmp.id}}</th>
      <td>{{tmp.worker}}</td>
      <td>{{tmp.manager}}</td>
      <td>
          <form role="form">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form_accpt|bootstrap}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Wyślij wniosek&nbsp<i class="far fa-save"></i></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="goBack()">Cofnij</button>
          </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
  No free days to accept
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Screen - result on page:
[image]

Comment: Make use of formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: thx I will try with that. I'll be back with results tomorrow.